# Why does `std::set::extract` not support heterogeneous lookup as `std::set::find`?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, c++14, standards

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    auto coll = std::set<std::string, std::less<>>{"abc"s, "xyz"s};
    coll.find("abc"sv);    // ok
    coll.extract("abc"sv); // error
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rd1EK6nEa)

**Why does** [`std::set::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) **not support heterogeneous lookup as** [`std::set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)**?**

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but you can bypass this limitation without much (if any) performance loss by using `coll.extract(coll.find("abc"sv));`

Comment: @Kaznov - Well, almost. IIUC the iterator you pass to `extract` must be valid. So checking against the end iterator before attempting the extraction is required. Still, good point about this having a very reasonable workaround.

Comment: It is proposed as [P2077R2](https://wg21.link/p2077r2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overloading of `std::set::extract()` in C++17 standard is as follows:

```
node_type extract(const_iterator position);  // (1)
node_type extract(const key_type& x);        // (2)
```

Assume that the following overload exist here (it does not exist in C++17 standard):

```
template<typename K>
node_type extract(const K& x);               // (3)
```

When an `iterator` object is passed to `extract()`, you would expect it to be implicitly converted to a `const_iterator` and (1) would be called, but in fact (3) would be selected.

This can be avoided by adding the following overload (not in the C++17 standard):

```
node_type extract(iterator position);        // (4)
```

However, even in this case, if you pass an object that implicitly convertible to `iterator` or `const_iterator`, (3) will be called.
This may not be what you expect.

---

[P2077R2](https://wg21.link/p2077r2) proposes to introduce the following overloads with constraints.

```
template<typename K>
node_type extract(K&& x);                    // (5)
```

Constraint: in addition to the presence of Compare::is_transparent, this overload will not be selected if `K&&` is implicitly convertible to `iterator` or `const_iterator`.